# Ring Progress Dialog with send Email

Tags: android

I developed app to send email using javaMail Api

send email inside process dialog But the dialog still works and I can't get out.

how I solve this problem:

```
Mail m = new Mail(AnthorEmail, AnthorPass);
String[] toArr = { supervisorEmail };
m.setTo(toArr);
m.setFrom("mbrm.yu@gmail.com");
m.setSubject("Supervisor's Email Verification, phone ID: " + supervisorIdentifer);
m.setBody(text);
final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Sender.this, "Please wait ...","Sending Email with Verification Code ...", true);
ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            try {
                if (m.send()) {
                } else {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}).start();
```

And in some cases app send emails but in last case email sent block email.

Comment: what is the error? post your logcat

Comment: move you `ringProgressDialog.dismiss();` inside of the try catch block.. Check if `ringProgressDialog != null` and `ringProgressDialog.isShowing()`